# How to access Whatsapp folder of Android 11 by using MediaStore API?

Tags: java, android

I really need your help because I'm stuck . I have already tryed all solutions I've found here in "stackoverflow" for this problem, but any of them worked for me.. I want to access External Storage folders in Android 11, How to use MediaStore for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read **WhatsApp** data ,

**Android 11: [EDIT]**

```
String path=  Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<=30  ? "WhatsApp/Media/Wallpaper":"Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/Wallpaper";
```

Add Read Permission:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Add Exact path:

```
String path=  "Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp <####>";
```

And finally read all data

```
private void loadData(String path) {
    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + path);
    folder.mkdirs();


    File[] allFiles = folder.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return (name.endsWith(".jpg") || name.endsWith(".jpeg") || name.endsWith(".png"));
        }
    });
    Log.e("Datas" , allFiles.toString());
}
```

Other paths:

```
        String pathWallPaper=  "Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/Wallpaper";
        String pathGif=  "Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Animated Gifs";
        String pathAudio=  "Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Audio";
        String pathDocs=  "Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Documents";
        String pathImage=  "Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images";
        String pathStickers=  "Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Stickers";
        String pathVideo=  "Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video";
```

Comment: Is it working on Android 11?

Comment: yes check my edit

Comment: No its not working on Android 11? I am trying the same code

Comment: can you show me the error log

Comment: I'm using `targetSdk 31`  its work for me

Comment: I want to access .Statuses folder of whatsapp?

Comment: By Simplying just Whatsapp Images it works fine

Comment: But I want to access .Statuses folder of whatsapp.

Comment: Yep its return null ,

Comment: can you check out this https://github.com/GauthamAsir/WhatsApp_Status_Saver

Comment: In this link.. MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is used but Google Play Store rejects the application which uses this permission.

Comment: yeah you can't access other applications data GGLPlay will reject your app

Comment: then what is the best solution to meet this requirement

Comment: Talking and talking and no one talks about media store anymore.

Comment: @ blackapps , do you have example for this?