# Whatsapp .Statuses path not working in my flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, dart, local-storage

I am sdk: '>=3.0.5 <4.0.0' in flutter and I am working in whatsapp status server app.It not showing any content about `

this is wa_path.dart file

```
class AppConstant {
  static String WHATSAPP_PATH =
      'storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses';
}
```

`

this is provider class

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp_status_server/constant/wa_path_constant.dart';

class GetStatusProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<FileSystemEntity> _getImages = [];
  List<FileSystemEntity> _getVideos = [];
  bool _isWhatsappAvailable = false;

  List<FileSystemEntity> get getImages => _getImages;
  List<FileSystemEntity> get getVideos => _getVideos;
  bool get isWhatsappAvailable => _isWhatsappAvailable;

  void getStatus(String ext) async {
    final status = await Permission.storage.request();

    if (status.isDenied) {
      Permission.storage.request();
      debugPrint("permission denied");
      return;
    }

    if (status.isGranted) {
      final directory = Directory(AppConstant.WHATSAPP_PATH);

      debugPrint(directory.toString());

      if (directory.existsSync()) {
        final items = directory.listSync();
        debugPrint(items.toString());
        if (ext == ".mp4") {
          _getVideos =
              items.where((element) => element.path.endsWith(".mp4")).toList();
          notifyListeners();
        } else {
          _getImages =
              items.where((element) => element.path.endsWith(".jpg")).toList();
          notifyListeners();
        }

        _isWhatsappAvailable = true;
        notifyListeners();
      } else {
        debugPrint('no whatsapp found');
        _isWhatsappAvailable = false;
        notifyListeners();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It showing empty list

I want to get the content of this path.I try to get the content of this path but it showing empty list.but other directories are working fine. .Statuses and .Links file are showing empty list. I am using android 11.

Comment: Q: Isn't this a duplicate of your earlier question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76744175/whatsapp-status-path-not-working-fin-my-flutter-app.  ALSO: look here (read both the post, and the comments): https://stackoverflow.com/a/70061993/421195